# Error connecting to newly configured FTP

Tags: samba, ftp

I just configured a Virtual Box following [the docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/6.06/ubuntu/serverguide/C/ftp-server.html). I am getting

> `ltdb: tdb(/var/lib/samba/group_mapping.ldb): tdb_mmap failed for size 77824 (Cannot allocate memory)`

when trying to connect to FTP. I think the same configuration worked before. What's wrong with this? I tried removing samba but still have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your virtual machine is out of memory. Try to give it some more.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vsftpd/+bug/723603